# How do I stop the error "The ordinal 3252 could not be located in the dynamic link library mongod.exe"?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Here are my development computer's specifications:

Windows 8.1 Single Language
Processor: Intel Core i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz 1.70GHz
Installed memory (RAM): 4.00 GB
System Type:  64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

I installed Mongo DB Win32 x86_64-2008 with SSL 3.0.7 pre

However, when I run "mongod.exe --dbpath db" from DOS command, I get the following error:

"The ordinal 3252 could not be located in the dynamic link library mongod.exe"

Why is the error showing up, and how do I stop the error?

Comment: Hello. Same issue here. Have you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ulysses-alves

I was previously downloading the zipped up MongoDB, and using the zipped up MongoDB would give me the error mentioned above.

I decided to used the standard MSI executable installation that MongoDB website , and it worked properly, but I don't really liked the MSI executable because it forcefully install MongoDB, and I would prefer controlling where MongoDB is placed.

Answer (score 3):

This problem exists if you have downloaded the zipped version. Try to place `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` in the bin directory.

Answer (score 3):

This error could occur if you've downloaded too old versions of openssl libs.
Here's link to binaries: https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/.

More on official openSSL web site : https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

At this time, the latest version is 1.0.2e.
Be sure to get the right dll for your architecture (32 or 64 bits).